# &#xA; is shown by XSLT

Tags: xslt, normalize-space

I want print attribute and put some values to it.

Input :

```
<figure id="fig_1">
 <dis>text</dis>
</figure>
```

my output:

```
<image ref="fig_1"
        comment="text the&#xA;                                    "/>
```

Tried code :

```
<xsl:template match="dis[parent::figure]">
    <xsl:variable name="fig_name" select="parent::fig/@id"/>
    <image ref="{$fig_name}">
        <xsl:attribute name="comment">
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </tps:image>
</xsl:template>
```

I want to remove all `&#xA;`. How can I do it.

Comment: The problem cannot be reproduced using the code you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use normalize-space() function to remove unnecessary white space.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />        
    <xsl:template match="long-desc[parent::fig]">
        <xsl:variable name="fig_name" select="parent::fig/@id"/>
        <image ref="{$fig_name}">
            <xsl:attribute name="comment">
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(text())"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </image>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Note that this could be simpified to `<image ref="{$fig_name}" comment="{normalize-space()}"/>. XSLT is less verbose than some people imagine.